# Creating a friendly name from a substring in kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have the following dataset in kusto:

```
let data = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, Name:string, Value:int)
        [
         datetime(2022-02-18 10:00:00 AM), "AX_100A_A00", 100,
         datetime(2022-02-18 10:01:00 AM), "BX_101B_B00", 200,
         datetime(2022-02-18 10:02:00 AM), "CX_102C_C00", 300,
         datetime(2022-02-18 10:03:00 AM), "DX_103D_D00", 400,  
         datetime(2022-02-18 10:04:00 AM), "EX_104E_E00", 500,
        ];
data
| summarize result = max(Value) by Floor_Name = substring(Name, 3, 4)
```

[image]

To illustrate what I am trying achieve here. Between the two underscores there is a code which represents a specific Location. What I need is to replace each value between those 2 underscores into a friendly name. **Please note this is just sample. In my real case scenario I need to be replacing 50 names**. I don't know if I should be defining a variable as dictionary which takes the previous name as **KEY** and the new name as **VALUE** then check for the existing key and replace it. I don't know if there is a better way to do it. I need to achieve the following:

100A --> New York

101B --> Geneva

102C --> France

103D --> US

104E --> Canada

[image]

Comment: It seems that you already have a good solution and that implementing it would have taken you less time than to post this question. Not sure why you did post it.

Comment: I didn't write the code. I want to see how it can be implemented in kusto if I want to use a dictionary. I was just showing you how I want the result to look like.

Comment: I meant that I don't understand why you post the question. You already wrote most of the code and it seems you are aware of the existence of dictionary in KQL. I'm curious to understand what was missing from your side in order to write a complete solution.

Comment: It is just the syntax of the dictionary that I was missing. This was the only part that I didn't wrote. I was searching on google for the syntax but I found the functions make_bag and pack when typing dictionary. So I just wanted to understand how to properly right. I am an idiot because it seems to be very simple but thank you very much for your answer !

Comment: You are just fine :-) I think the concept of `dynamic` is not completely straight forward. See updated answer for relevant links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The dynamic data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic)
or
[bag_pack(), pack()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packfunction)

```
let data = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, Name:string, Value:int)
        [
         datetime(2022-02-18 10:00:00 AM), "AX_100A_A00", 100,
         datetime(2022-02-18 10:01:00 AM), "BX_101B_B00", 200,
         datetime(2022-02-18 10:02:00 AM), "CX_102C_C00", 300,
         datetime(2022-02-18 10:03:00 AM), "DX_103D_D00", 400,  
         datetime(2022-02-18 10:04:00 AM), "EX_104E_E00", 500,
        ];
let mydict = dynamic(
    {
         "100A":"New York"
        ,"101B":"Geneva"
        ,"102C":"France"
        ,"103D":"US"
        ,"104E":"Canada"
    }
);
data
| summarize result = max(Value) by Floor_Name = tostring(mydict[substring(Name, 3, 4)])
```

| Floor_Name | result |
| --- | --- |
| New York | 100 |
| Geneva | 200 |
| France | 300 |
| US | 400 |
| Canada | 500 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42STWuDQBCG74L/YdiTgoF1tVAsPRg1PTWXftASyjJJliJ1tejaNv347501CbY5KYK78%207z7jgzlTKwRYNwOXwMrivl3ZZadQb1a0IxZWgXwBK1SjrTlvVzAPdY9Sopa%20O7Dhye1biEI%20YJLsSMi1l4DiFPuH0hvfYDYOmDDDlPZco5C0jkwQQ%20HPm55cO5nA%208mMaLkc8sLzKZDXw0jY9GPrd8lMt84GPiASY4xKNDYR3iQhaDw9m/DJ4uXKei1ujdttwY25xdjbrcePsjX39uYraMLGFL9Q6PTfvCRi1gtkSkXalaveGJIjJSFi3WG3WiRDkpdzcn0bigaIY1bo9OP67jU6J2cFznG7pea2zLTwWt6vrKpq3xwxuGxYf1DhZV07TSThJJptlPk7f/x1XXrw8Be4BaQlX1n/xf1xU8DKECAAA=)

Comment: Hey David ! I just have a question here. Is it possible to add a condition which checks if the word between the 2 underscores doesn't exist as key in the dictionary, then just display it as it is. However if it does exist in the dictionary, then display its friendly name. So for example, if 100A doesn't exist as a key in the dictionary, then what will appear in the column is 100A, however if it does exist in the dictionary then display its friendly name in this case New York.

Comment: Hey :-)  Please post a new question for this

Comment: Is it okay for me to use your code mentioned here in the new post just for simplicity ?

Comment: Sure ............